# Error 1904 Module .dll failed to register

Tags: windows-7, dll

while i was trying to install the OpenTouchConverstation from Alcatel i got the following error message:

**Product: OpenTouch Conversation -- Error 1904. Module DSSourceFilter.dll failed to register.  HRESULT -2147024770.  Contact your support personnel.**

I tried to manually register the dll but that also failed.
I had this problem with 10 Laptos so far.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1) Contact Alcatel support

Option 2) See if the DLL has a dependency, for which you can use dependency walker from here http://www.dependencywalker.com/

It's most likely depending on Visual C++ Runtime or one of the .Net Framework libraries. Make sure you have those installed, and try your OpenTouch install again.

Comment: Hey, it was the x86 version of the Visual C++ Runtime Version 12. I just had to install it manually because it isnt in the OTC install file. Thx for your help :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad it worked :)